# Why is setOnItemLongClickListener not working?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sql-delete

I am generating a `Listview` from a Sqlite database using a `SimpleAdapter`. I want to delete the item on long pressing the row on the phone. But the `listview` row is not responding to anything on long pressing. Can anyone guide me in this matter?
My codes are as follows:

`Lists.java`

```
  ListView l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  l.setLongClickable(true);
  details=db.getlocationdetails();
  if((details=db.getlocationdetails()).size()!=0)
  {

      ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(Lists.this,details,R.layout.testviewnew,new String[]{"locname","profile"},new int[]{R.id.locationame,R.id.proname});
      l.setAdapter(k);
  }
 l.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s=String.valueOf(arg2);
        db.deleterow(s);
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

And this is my database code:

```
public void deleterow(String id) {
Log.d(LOGCAT,"delete");
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  animals where savedlocation='"+ id +"'";
Log.d("query",deleteQuery);     
database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
database.close();
}
```

And here are my xml files

activity_lists.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

</ListView>
```

testviewnew.xml

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ishutup_pointer" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locationame"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Profile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/proname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ishutup_edit" />
```

Comment: did you have any error?

Comment: No,When I pressed the row for a long time there was no response. No errors on the log as such

Comment: put a log in `onItemLongClick` ... do you see the log?

Comment: when I long pressed it the row didn't get highlighted

Comment: did you have any clickable widget on your row? like button or checkbox?

Comment: No log errors for long press

Comment: Ya. I have a 2 ImageViews and 4 Textviews. i will post the xml files

Comment: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on parrent of `testviewnew` (like `linearlayout` or `relativelayout`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two imageButton in your xml but you don't have any listener on those, so you can change that with imageView. so your code must be:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ishutup_pointer" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locationame"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Profile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/proname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ishutup_edit" />
```

as your `imageButton` want to listen click as default, if you want don't change your code you can add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on parrent of `testviewnew`  like as i said on comment to remove listening on those